# Couchdb: OS process timed out

Tags: couchdb

I'm suffering from an intermittent but severe couchdb error.

This error is of the form of "OS process timed out." as shown in
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8629425/

My current troubleshooting is as follows:

- There is no big document, no heavy load on the server and few requests on couchdb.
- Setting "query_server_config/os_process_limit" and "couchdb/os_process_timeout" do not seem to help, the problem is somewhere else.
- The bug happened in version 1.2, I migrated to 1.6 and the bug is still there.
- Restarting couchdb does not solve the error

Any clue on how to diagnose and fix the problem?

Comment: The error seems to be occurring in the `design/_auth` ddoc in the users database. Can you delete the users database via futon and check again. When you delete the database via futon couchdb will create it again for you (automatically) and restore it to it's original state. I am guessing that maybe you made some change to validate_doc_update in `_auth` and it is throwing errors.

Comment: the timeout happens after 5 seconds (seems to be related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1333)

Comment: when I trigger "Verify your installation" in Futon, I get "X: CouchError: {gen_server,call,[couch_query_servers,{get_proc,<<"javascript">>},infinity]}"

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that the query server could not even start.

The same error message "Couchdb: OS process timed out" is used for very different errors:

- query server executable not found
- query server executable not executable (wrong permissions)
- query server crashes at startup
- query server hangs
- query server replies garbage
- query invalid
- query execution takes too long

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2431

Answer (score 1):

I have had the similar issue with couchdb. I am running couchdb 2.1.2 on raspberryPI.  So I was not sure about what could make this issue for me. ( cpu or ram limits )
So what I have done:

1) reserve 2 cpu for couchdb service in docker compose in deploy section. One for couchjs for indexing.

```
resources:
  reservations:
    cpus: '2.00'
```

2) Update local.ini config file. local.ini overrides default.ini config file

```
[couchdb]
os_process_timeout = 30000
[cluster]
q=1
n=1
[fabric]
all_docs_concurrency = 4
[log]
level = debug
```

PS: changes only os_process_timeout parameter didnot help.  I am not sure what did the "trick" cluster or fabric changes.